# How to keep negative sign from character into numeric

Tags: r

I wanted to keep negative sign of character while converting it into numeric class. But ended up getting a warning like NAs introduced by coercion.

```
test <- c("001","00-2","0003")
test <- as.numeric(as.character(test))
```

I expect the real output is:

1 -2 3

But the current output is:

1 NA 3

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) sub** Remove leading 0's and then convert:

```
as.numeric(sub("^0+", "", test))
## [1]  1 -2  3
```

**2) trimws** In R 3.6 or later this would also work:

```
as.numeric(trimws(test, "left", 0))
## [1]  1 -2  3
```

### Edge case

**3) paste0** If it is possible to have all zeros then the `sub` will reduce that string to an empty string so assuming that we have no decimals we can do this:

```
test2 <- c(test, "00")
as.numeric(sub("^0+", "", paste0(test2, ".0")))
## [1]  1 -2  3  0
```

**3a)** or this:

```
as.numeric(sub("^0*(.)", "\\1", test2))
## [1]  1 -2  3  0
```

Comment: I tried all the codes and they work perfectly.Thanks @G. Grothendieck for your help! I'm beginner in R and not quite familiar with sub functionalities, btw thanks for the idea!